# Determining the smallest possible value

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If both $11^2$ and $3^3$ are factors of the number $a \times 4^3 \times 6^2 \times 13^{11}$, then what is the smallest possible value of a?

> IS there any trick to answer this type question quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As $(4,11)=(6,11)=(13,11)=1$

$11^2$ must divide  $a$

Observe that the highest power of $3$ in $4^3 \times 6^2 \times 13^{11}$ is $2$

So, $3$ must divide $a$

$\implies $lcm$(11^2,3)$ must divide $a$

Comment: Can you elaborate the first line plz

Comment: @ComplexGuy, $(a,b)=$gcd$(a,b)$

Comment: @ComplexGuy, another fact if $c$ divides $a\cdot b$ and $(c,a)=1, c$ must divide $b$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  work on the factorization of the number to get it in terms of primes.  You need three factors of $3$ and two of $11$.  How many do you have?

Comment: we need one 3 and two 11 . 
So the answer will be = $11^2\times 3$?

Comment: That is correct.